# What is the best approach to stop your platform's users to "sniff" the frontend requests to backend and modify them?

Tags: rest, security, backend, api-design, api-security

So I have a platform that works like this: Users can create accounts by logging in with their Google **(I USE AUTH0)** and then they can create "Projects" which contain lots of other unimportant stuff regarding my current problem (like todo lists, ability to upload files etc; they can also Edit the project by changing some of it's attributes like name, description, theme and so on). There is a home page where everyone can see each other's projects and access them (but not upload files, change the tasks in the to do lists; this is possible only by the person that owns it).
By using a tool like Burp, people can see the request made from frontend to backend, for example when accessing one of the projects, and modify it on the fly.

*This is what it looks like inside Burp when they access one of the projects:*
[image]

As you can see there is a Get request to `/projects/idOfTheProject`; they can replace the *GET* with *DELETE* for example and they will successfully delete it; they can also see what is sent to the backend when a project is edited (name changed, description, thumbnail picture etc) and change anything they want about it.
How should I prevent this?

**What I've looked at so far:**
a. JWT - Probably the best fitting for my situation, but required the most work to be done (as I already have my platform almost finished with no such a security measure implemented yet, so I may need to rewrite a lot of things in both backend and frontend)

b. Sending the user's id that initiated the action as well to the backend and verify if it has the necessary privileges - *the worst solution* as users can access each other's profile and see the id, then just change another field in the request's JSON

c. Have a sort of token for each user and send that instead of the user's id - in this way somebody can't get your token by just looking at the communication between frontend and backend (only if it is using *YOUR* account). That token should be taken maybe somewhere from the auth0 when they create their account? If they provide something like that; or I can just create it myself and store it alongside the other user variables. You would still see the requests in plain text but even if you modified something you would still have to "guess" the owner's token, which will be impossible.

For frontend I use NextJS and for backend Flask.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: How do you now ensure, that only logged in users can access your API? To my understanding, Auth0 is based on OAuth2, and therefore you would have to send your JWT token from the frontend to the backend with every request in the `Authorization` header anyways. Is this the case or do you do that login check differently?

Comment: So the auth0 has an id for each account and that is the user id I use to store it in the database as well. Auth0 gives me the id of the logged in user. The idea mentioned on point c is that they are not prevented from accessing it, but without the token it is useless, as the request will be rejected by the backend

Comment: Oauth2 usually not only gives you the ID of the logged in user, but also can specify the actions that user is allowed to perform. You would have to configure this in Auth0 - I'm not familiar with that provider, but it seems that they have some API to manage "Access". I definitely would recommend to use your option a) because the other 2 options mean even more work for you, you would have to implement a complete management for the access model and you will have to implement storage of user (authorization) data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TL;DR is that you don’t. A determined user will always be able to see what requests are being sent out by the code running on their computer and over their network. What you are describing when asking how to prevent people from “sniffing” these requests is security through obscurity, which isn’t actually secure at all.

What you should do instead is have an authorization system on your backend which will check if the current user can perform a given action on a given resource. For example, verifying that a user is an administrator before allowing them to delete a blog post, or making sure that the current user is on the same account as another user before allowing the current user to see details about the other user.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How should the backend check for the user's permission without receiving anything from the frontend that is "sniffable" and editable. Can you link  resource regarding your idea please?

Comment: It should receive information from the frontend! The frontend will always be able to edit anything that it sends in, so your backend has to be the actual authority on if a request is valid or not. There are two separate but related concepts you might want to dig more into, authentication and authorization. Authentication is how your backend knows who is making the request, and can be handled in many ways (such as JWTs, Sessions, etc). Authorization is insuring that whoever is making the request has permission to do so. Common authorization shemas include ACLs, RBAC, model permissions, etc.

Comment: So by searching about those subjects I came across this: [link](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/python/01-authorization) from auth0 docs but I still have a logical problem. When they talk about permissions, how should I set those in order for a user to be able to only delete HIS projects? 'cause the permissions here seem pretty generic (for example, in my case: "delete:project" could be a permission, but I want the user to be able to delete specific projects)